# nodemon restarting due to changes.... constante una vez que hago cualquier cambio. No termina de reiniciarlo

Tags: nodejs, express

Cada vez que hago un cambio en uno de los archivos del servidor y le doy a guardar, el mensaje `[nodemon] restarting due to changes...` es lo único que veo. **Lo tengo instalado globalmente**. He probado reinstalando pero como si nada... No lo he puesto como `devDependencies` ni `dependencies` porque al estar globalmente...

He probado poniendo `-L` como he visto en otras respuestas y también `--delay 1` pero nada. También he probado con `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` en la powershell de **Windows 10 Pro Versión 21H1 (compilación de SO 19043, 1151)** de 64b its (por si sirve ese dato)  y tampoco ha servido.

Y es un fastidio tener que darle **Ctrl + C** para detenerlo y volver a iniciarlo. Porque para eso, mejor no tener instalado el nodemon. Inicio y paro el servidor cuando quiera y listo. Y, por
supuesto, una vez que se pone el mensaje de "reiniciando debido a cambios" no deja escribir en la consola el comando `rs` para reiniciar. Ni rs ni nada, de hecho.

La línea del script en el **package.json** es la siguiente:

```json
"dev": "nodemon -L app --delay 1",
```

Versión de **node**: `v14.17.4`. Versión de **express**: `^4.17.1`. Versión de **nodemon**: `2.0.12`. Versión de **npm**: `6.14.14`.

---

Adjunto el package.json completo:

```json
{
  "name": "AlgNode",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Alg versión node. Pruebas.",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon -L app.js --delay 1",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "una URL de repositorio de git de este proyecto normal y corriente"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "una URL generada automáticamente de git"
  },
  "homepage": "una URL generada automáticamente con el readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5", // No lo estoy usando aún, nada más está instalado
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-handlebars": "^5.3.2",
    "mongoose": "^5.13.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0"
  }
}
```

¡Muchas  gracias de antemano!

Comment: ¿`app` o `app.js`?

Comment: Dado que se trata de un archivo *.js*, lo hago con **app** en vez de **app.js**. No se me había ocurrido. De hecho, acabo de probarlo, por las dudas, ya que lo comentabas, y tiene exactamente el mismo efecto.

Comment: ¿Podrías editar tu pregunta y mostrar qué más tenés en tu `package.json`? Puede que sea otro el problema.

Comment: @padaleiana, ya está actualizado.

Comment: ¿Intentaste agregar en la sección de `scripts` `"start": "node app.js"`?

Comment: Acabo de intentarlo y en vez de un `restarting due to changes...` me salen 2 seguidos, pero igualmente no reinicia (corriendo el script npm start (habiendo puesto el script sugerido en la sección correspondiente)

Comment: Al parecer, según esta [issue](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/1882), no sos el único con el mismo problema. En caso de que logres solucionarlo, por favor, escribilo como respuesta.

Comment: Parece que tienes razón, @padaleiana No lo dudes: si lo logro solucionar, lo pondré como respuesta. ¡Muchas gracias!